# How to retrieve a sub-string from a string that changes dynamically with respect to multiple delimiters through Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, split

I wonder if its possible to remove part of the scraped string like:

```
Wujek Drew / Uncle Drew
```

into

`Uncle Drew`

Of course, as it is web scraping, the titles will be different every time, so what can I do here to get the result above?

---

### Update

I forgot to add something that need to be removed also. **Wujek Drew / Uncle Drew (2018)** I Will need to delete the data at the end of the string.

Comment: Do you always want to ignore everything up to a slash character?  Or can that change too?

Comment: The slash may be used to remove the first part of the sentence if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove first part of the scraped string separated by **/** character you can use the following solution:

```
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath").get_attribute("innerHTML").split("/")[1]
```

---

As per your comment update if you want to extract the sub-string **Uncle Drew** from the string **Wujek Drew / Uncle Drew (2018)** you can use the following solution:

```
import re

value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath").get_attribute("innerHTML")
#value='Wujek Drew / Uncle Drew (2018)'
print(re.split('[/()]',value)[1])
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add something that need to be removed also. Wujek Drew / Uncle Drew (2018) I Will need to delete the data at the end of the string. Tried to play with your solution but struggling.

Comment: @serengeti Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: Thanks for update. Tried it and here is what I got. https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HBLusR8.png

Comment: @serengeti I have dropped the `split("/")[1]` part in the answer update and handled with `re.split()`. Please cross check.

Comment: yeah I already checked that and gave you the result on screenshot. so, with this - only the date is printed.

Comment: oh, my bad, I used it with the earlier function sorry. now its looks good. thanks for support :)

Comment: Okay :) cool down. Watch carefully. In the first version of my answer I have extracted the entire `innerHTML` and invoked `split()` in the same step. Where as in the updated version of my answer, in the first step I have extracted the entire `innerHTML` only. In the next line I have performed the `split()`. There is a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179211/discussion-between-serengeti-and-debanjanb).